# How to add password protection to already created LINQ to SQL Database

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, windows-phone, onedrive

I'm using LINQ to SQL Database in Windows Phone 8.1 developmentand using below connection string:

```
public class MyAppDBContext : DataContext
{
   public static string ConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/MyAppDB.sdf";
   public MyAppDBContext() : base(ConnectionString) { }

   //Standart DBContext Code
   ...
}
```

As you can see there is no password protection. I'm looking for a solution to add password to current database. After a long research i saw this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202861(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Supportedproperties)

> You cannot encrypt a database after it has been created.

This is a live app on the store and there are thousands of users already downloaded. Planning to add OneDrive backup option and don't want to upload the DB to user's OneDrive without encrpyting the database. This is very important feature and i'm unable to add this feature without protecting the DB. Any idea mighty StackOVerFlow masters?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only worried about the backup, you could use some kind of encrypted container like a .zip file and password protect that instead of the database.

Comment: That's a case but couldn't find a good solution to encrypt that backup. Any idea?